# Max BIN Volume under constraints for single box

Tags: excel, optimization, vba

I have a single box with sides l, w, h (natural numbers). I have to pack this standard box to the BIN under constraints: Longest BIN side <=150, Longest BIN side + 2*(sum of other 2 sides)<=300. Based on Lagrange Multipliers the maximum BIN volume and length of sides under these constraints are  100x50x50=250000. The optimal BIN sides should be close to 100x50x50 and must have maximum volume. Now the below code works, but for a box with small sides it is taking more time. For example, if box sides are 1x1x1, then it calculates all options 150x150x150 under above constraints. If anybody has better idea how to improve this code, please help.

```
`Sub Macro1()

l = Sheets("list").Range("a" & 2)'45
w = Sheets("list").Range("b" & 2)'20
h = Sheets("list").Range("c" & 2)'30

result = 150 / l
ll = Math.Round(150 / l, 0)
If result <> ll Then
ll = ll + 1
Else
End If

result = 150 / w
lw = Math.Round(150 / w, 0)
If result <> lw Then
lw = lw + 1
Else
End If

result = 150 / h
lh = Math.Round(150 / h, 0)
If result <> lh Then
lh = lh + 1
Else
End If

Dim londis() As Double
Dim shortdis() As Double
Dim options() As Double

ReDim options(lw * ll * lh)
ReDim longdis(lw * ll * lh)
ReDim shortdis(lw * ll * lh)
k = 6
s = 0
`
For i = 0 To lh

For j = 0 To lw

For n = 0 To ll
    summa = i * h + j * w + n * l
    If summa <= 150 Then
        'Sheets("list").Range("a" & k) = summa
        s = s + 1
        options(s) = summa
        'longdis(s) = 100 - summa
        'shortdis(s) = 50 - summa
        If summa > 100 Then
            longdis(s) = 100 - summa
        Else
            longdis(s) = summa - 100
        End If

        If summa <= 50 Then
            shortdis(s) = summa - 50
        Else
            shortdis(s) = 50 - summa
        End If

        k = k + 1
    Else
        GoTo 1
    End If

Next n

1:
Next j

Next i

For i = 1 To s - 1

    For j = i + 1 To s
        If shortdis(i) < shortdis(j) Then
            pTemp1 = options(i)
            pTemp2 = longdis(i)
            pTemp3 = shortdis(i)
            options(i) = options(j)
            shortdis(i) = shortdis(j)
            longdis(i) = longdis(j)
            options(j) = pTemp1
            longdis(j) = pTemp2
            shortdis(j) = pTemp3
        Else
        End If
    Next j
Next i

t = 1
maxVol = 0
pT = 0
pL = 0
prodVol = l * w * h
maxPosUnit = Int(250000 / prodVol)
maxPosVol = maxPosUnit * prodVol
Do While t < s - 2

longside = 300 - 2 * (options(t) + options(t + 1))

    For i = 1 To s
        If options(i) <= longside Then
        vol = options(i) * options(t) * options(t + 1)
            If vol > maxVol Then
                maxVol = vol
                pT = t
                pL = i
            Else
            End If
        Else
        End If

        If options(i) = longside Then
            Exit Do
        End If
Next i

t = t + 1

Loop

Sheets("list").Range("d" & 2) = prodVol
Sheets("list").Range("e" & 2) = maxPosUnit
'Sheets("list").Range("f" & 2) = 250000 - maxPosVol

Sheets("list").Range("a" & 3) = options(pT)
Sheets("list").Range("b" & 3) = options(pT + 1)
Sheets("list").Range("c" & 3) = options(pL)
boxVol = options(pT) * options(pT + 1) * options(pL)
Sheets("list").Range("d" & 3) = boxVol
Sheets("list").Range("e" & 3) = Int(boxVol / prodVol)
Sheets("list").Range("f" & 3) = boxVol - Int(boxVol / prodVol) * prodVol
End Sub
```